# Executing stored procedure from Java, other than with JDBC CallableStatement

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement, ocpjp

I am preparing the *Java 7* certification using one of the mock test suites available.

One of the test questions I stumbled upon is about the *JDBC* `CallableStatement` class, and one of the correct answers (according to the tool) is:

> A CallableStatement is **the only way** for a Java program to execute
>   stored procedures in the database if the procedure has in and out
>   parameters.

This seems very presumptuous to me and I was wondering if there are existing libraries out there (maybe proprietary db libraries for instance) which allow running stored procedures without *JDBC*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyBatis, Hibernate/JPA and other open source framework all use JDBC under the table.

Comment: So what you and @BrettOkken are really saying is that the statement: "A `CallableStatement` is **the only way** for a Java program to execute stored procedures in the database if the procedure has in and out parameters." is actually and absolutely true, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I know

Comment: Well then, I'll eat my hat, not so presumptuous after all :) Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on how *nuanced* an answer for which they're looking. Since most *Java* *SQL* technologies/frameworks depend on *JDBC* at some level, one could perhaps say that they abstract that away, but it's still technically involved.

However, I could use, for example, [*MyBatis*](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/index.html), to call a *stored procedure* without ever **directly** invoking *CallableStatement* or anything related to *JDBC*. In that case, I would define a `<select>` statement in the *mapper file* which invoked the *stored procedure*. It could both take arguments and return values.

Comment: For the actual stored procedure to be executed, a `CallabeStatement` will be used. Even if it is used indirectly, it is still used.